# pycurl link error after upgrade from Yosemite to High Sierra

Tags: python, linker-errors

I just upgraded from Yosemite to High Sierra, which worked quite well, with the only exception that I have a bug in pycurl.

```
    import pycurl
ImportError: No module named pycurl
```

so I did

```
pip uninstall pycurl
```

and

```
pip install --no-cache-dir --compile pycurl
```

but now it results in a clang error

```
    clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup build/temp.macosx-10.10-x86_64-2.7/src/docstrings.o build/temp.macosx-10.10-x86_64-2.7/src/easy.o build/temp.macosx-10.10-x86_64-2.7/src/module.o build/temp.macosx-10.10-x86_64-2.7/src/multi.o build/temp.macosx-10.10-x86_64-2.7/src/oscompat.o build/temp.macosx-10.10-x86_64-2.7/src/pythoncompat.o build/temp.macosx-10.10-x86_64-2.7/src/share.o build/temp.macosx-10.10-x86_64-2.7/src/stringcompat.o build/temp.macosx-10.10-x86_64-2.7/src/threadsupport.o -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/sqlite/lib -lssl3 -lcurl -o build/lib.macosx-10.10-x86_64-2.7/pycurl.so
ld: library not found for -lssl3
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/5h/h0hwdpps0cd_v2k_m652wwzm0000gq/T/pip-build-1rx5q1/pycurl/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/5h/h0hwdpps0cd_v2k_m652wwzm0000gq/T/pip-MkzYNt-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/5h/h0hwdpps0cd_v2k_m652wwzm0000gq/T/pip-build-1rx5q1/pycurl/
```

any idea what is going on here?

Answer (score 8):

this fixed it...

export PYCURL_SSL_LIBRARY=openssl